# php foreach loop to array in specific format

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm working with `php_xlsxwriter`, which takes php and outputs it to Excel.

Their sample code for "what gets output" is:

```
$data2 = array(
    array('2003','01','343.12'),
    array('2003','02','353.12'),
    array('2003','03','363.12'),
    array('2003','04','373.12'),
);
```

which of course outputs 4 lines to an Excel spreadsheet.  For some reason ONLY an array written like this will output successfully.  I've tried building arrays in other ways, but it causes the plugin to fail.

As such, I'm inputting data from an ajax call into this page, which contains my array of say... 50 elements, but I can't figure out how to write the `foreach` loop so that it builds a complete list.  Right now, it's just outputting the LAST element in the array.

```
foreach ($xlString as &$c) {

  $s = $c[0];
  $p = $c[1];
  $l = $c[2];
  $a = $c[3]; 

  $data1 = array(

      array($s,$p,$l,$a),

  );

}
```

I understand **WHY** this is - because I'm overwriting `$data1` each time I run the `foreach` loop - but I don't know how to change the code so that I don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare $data outside the array, then add your results as a new element within the loop

```
$data = array()
foreach ($xlString as &$c) {

  $s = $c[0];
  $p = $c[1];
  $l = $c[2];
  $a = $c[3]; 

  $data1[] = array(

      array($s,$p,$l,$a),

  );

}
```